# Why is the method bindTo of RXSwift failing

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I update a cell by the following code. When cell's data is loaded, the cell looks well at first the time, but when I make some changes on property value of 'selected', the 'bindTo' has no effect? why?

> **MyController.swift**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var model = xxxxxxxxx
    cell.setModel(model)
}
```

> **MyTableViewCell.swift**:

```
var model = PublishSubject<MyClass>()

func setModel(newModel: MyClass) {
   self.model.onNext(newModel)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   // Initialization code
   self.setup()
}

func setup() {
   model.map{$0.selected}
        .bindTo(selectButton.rx_selected)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyTableViewCell.swift:
let model = Variable(MyClass())
 func setModel(newModel: MyClass) {
        self.model.value = newModel
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        model.map{$0.selected}.bindTo(selectButton.rx_selected).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example,When i change value of 'selected' property by a notification or another view, the state of 'selectButton'  should change.

Comment: is there one button or one for each cell?

Comment: Every cell has a button.

Comment: Add fragment which shows how do you update 'selected' property of your model. As I can see, probably, your button will be updated only when 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' is launched again (when you scroll table eg. down/up and back to previous position).